# Which version of Banshee in repos with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, banshee, software-sources, install-from-source

I need to know which version of `Banshee` is the one in repos of `Ubuntu 14.04`

According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/sound/banshee

It is `2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu2`, so its is `2.9.0` OR `2.6.2`??

Knowing that, Banshee codebase has the two releases (`2.9.0` and `2.6.2`) and between the two there are 4 months of work. (according to https://github.com/GNOME/banshee/releases)

Comment: what's your actual question is?

Comment: What specific part you couldn't understand so I can make it clear for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the version string (`2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu2`), this is Banshee 2.6.2.

The reasoning the version string looks like this is probably because version 2.9.0 was uploaded at some point, but because of some regression (or problem, or something else), they had to go back to version 2.6.2. However, any new version they upload has to be greater than the previous version. Therefore, the only (standard) way to have 2.6.2 be "more" than 2.9.0 is to have the version string look like `2.9.0+really2.6.2-2ubuntu2`.

Here's the reasoning (From https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/banshee/+changelog):

```
banshee (2.9.0+really2.6.1-0ubuntu1) trusty; urgency=low

  * [fbf05ca] Imported Upstream version 2.9.0+really2.6.1:
    Downgrade to 2.6.1 -- 2.9.x is unstable and 3.0 won't arrive in time for
    release
  * [22de440] Revert packaging to 2.6.1-2ubuntu1
  * [7357b73] Merge changes from 2.6.1-5
  * [a7156c0] Filter out libgpod-cil-dev versions built against gtk#3
  * [e7c634d] Update dversionmangle for extracting +really version out
 -- Chow Loong Jin <hyperair@debian.org>   Sun, 09 Feb 2014 23:06:03 +0800
```