# Banshee for Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, banshee

I am unable to find a banshee package for ubuntu 19.04. Is there a banshee package for Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: I don't think there is and hasn't been probably for many years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no. Their last release was [five years ago](http://banshee.fm/), their last contribution to [git](https://git-scm.com/) was [three years ago](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/banshee/), and you're [not the only one](http://banshee.fm/support/forum/) asking.

Comment: Wow...That is sad!  What is a popular replacement other than rythmbox (not a fan)?

Comment: That, my friend, is a Software Recommendation, and those sit in a different pew of the Church of Stack Exchange: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com  Oh, look! 
 https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/music-library-capable-player-for-windows-that-is-database-compatible-to-banshee

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463368/which-version-of-banshee-in-repos-with-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Banshee, and get its benefits (none of which are available in ANY other media player or tag editor), and still have Ubuntu, then the only option is to have either a spare netbook or separate partition to run 16.04. I have an old netbook running 16.04 based wattOS R10, that I use only for Banshee & data backup.

Alternatively, use another distro, perhaps a minimum Debian from a net install.

Banshee has been abandoned by its developer, and since 16.10, Ubuntu has been dropping support for a multitude of properly installable software and libraries, in favor of snap applications and such like.

In my experience, there is no alternative to Banshee. I have tried Kid3, Rhythmbox, and QuodLibet, and none of them have Banshee's functionality.

Comment: Please do not send the same answer to different questions.